# "To reason most absurd" in Hamlet

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, shakespeare

Here's from Hamlet, Act 1, Scene 2
(The Arden Shakeseare edited by Harold Jenkins)

> Fie, 'tis a fault to heaven,
>   A fault against the dead, a fault to nature,
>   **To reason most absurd**, whose common theme
>   Is death of fathers, and who still hath cried
>   From the first corse till he that died today,
>   'This must be so'.
>   <sub>(Emphasis added)</sub>

I understand the grammar structure of this sentence *except* "To reason most absurd".
I guess it means "it is irrational", but I can't analyze it grammatically.

Comment: It _is_ poetry you know, where anything goes.

Comment: The question has got two downvotes so far.
What's the reason for the downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Reason* here is a noun, meaning the reasoning capacity, and is the object of the preposition *to*. Hamlet says that his grief appears to any rational judgment as 'most absurd'.

The ordinary sequence, *most absurd to reason*, is inverted to put the emphasis on *absurd*: *-surd* is the heaviest syllable in this line, led up to with the 'extra' foot *-son most*, which impels the rhythmic stress forward onto the third foot, *absurd*.

Incidentally, *reason* is also the referent of *whose*: the death of fathers is the common theme of reason.

Comment: "The ordinary sequence, *most absurd to reason*, is inverted to put the emphasis on absurd:"
I think "'tis a fault" is supposed to be placed just before "To reason most absurd".
What do you think?

Comment: @ivanhoescott No, that would wreck the meter. *A fault* is there only in sense, not in words, just as *tis* is there in sense before the two preceding *faults* - it's ordinary ellipsis.

Comment: "No, that would wreck the meter."
Maybe it was my English's fault.
I didn't mean that "'tis a fault" was somehow dropped from the text.
I meant it should be placed there in *sense*.
If that is the case, it seems that "'tis a fault to reason most absurd" does not make sense.

Comment: @ivanhoescott The misunderstanding was mine: I thought you were proposing a textual emendation! Yes, the sense is *Tis a fault to reason most absurd*.

Comment: Then, it means "'Tis a fault most absurd to reason" in your interpretation.
So "most absurd" is describing "fault", i.e. it means "'Tis a most absurd fault to reason", right?

Comment: @ivanhoescott Right.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that ‘it’ is a fault to or against:

- to heaven
- against the dead
- to nature
- to (the) reason (that is) most absurd

Whether it makes sense to speak of *absurd reason* is a different matter—this is Shakespeare, after all, who is not exactly known for holding back on the poetic licence.

But grammatically, *reason most absurd* is a noun phrase consisting of a head noun and a postpositioned adjectival modifier phrase, which itself consists of the adjective *absurd* modified by the adverb *most*.

Answer (score 0):

to reason

here "to" is a preposition and reason is a noun. it is not an infinitive.

most absurd - it is highly illogical. "Most" meaning "Quite" and not "The most (quantity)" .

Here is an example sentence:
(To me), you are beautiful. (of course, you generally don't want to start sentences with prepositions.)

another example:
(To lions), elk are prey.

He is saying that

(To reason) [it is] most absurd.

Comment: On the contrary, you very often do want to start sentences with prepositions. From what deluded source did you gather that idea? For most of us, it's small letters that should be avoided there.